# Is the cosine angle between two R.V. an (approximation) not equality to the correlation coefficient?

Tags: statistics, inner-products, variance, covariance, correlation

I have seen in websites that given two R.V. $X,Y$, if $$
\cos(\theta)=\frac{X\cdot Y}{\|X\|_2\|Y\|_2}
$$
and
$$
\rho=\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)}}
$$then

$$
\cos(\theta)=\rho
$$

---

This identity implies $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=X\cdot Y$. Isn't $X\cdot Y$ the Maximum Likelihood Estimate for the covariance missing some factors? If true then the equation above is not equality but rather $≈$ as the samples become bigger.

Next is the denominator which implies  that $$ \text{Var}(X)= \| X\|_2 ^2$$.
Again, isn't the right side not an identity but rather an estimator (MLE) to the variance of $X$?
Isn't $$ \rho ≈ \cos(\theta)$$

---

I have also seen the dot product **(without the denominator in the first equation I've given but being more general using inner products)**  being used to measure correlation in some papers like Least Angle Regression. I am confused about the relationship between dot products and correlation. This leads me to a general question:

Is
$$
\langle X,X\rangle = \text{Var}(X)
$$
in Euclidean space.

Comment: One defines an inner product by setting (for real random variables) $X\cdot Y = Cov(X,Y)$. Thus, for the corresponding norm, we get $\lvert \lvert X \rvert\rvert_2^2 = Cov(X,X) = \text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite May I ask about that definition? Isn't $Cov(X,Y)=E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]$ which can be either a summation or integral?

Comment: That is not quite true (edit: with your edit the formula is true), we have $Cov(X,Y) = E((X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_Y))$. If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete this is a sum, and if they are continuous it is indeed an integral. In fact one can write both of the cases above as a (Lebesgue) integral.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite Assuming centered dataset, then $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)$. I fail to see the final answer as an inner product.

Comment: The point is that $X\cdot Y$ is defined as $Cov(X,Y)$. So the equality you are asking about is essentially true by definition.

Comment: Ohh! That clears it up. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$X \cdot Y$ is a random variable.

$\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ is an expected value.

- ---- addendum  ----*

There is some confusion of terminolgy in your post.

If $\bf X , \bf Y$ are two random **vectors** (in $m$-space) then their dot product is
a random **variable**
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 {\bf X},{\bf Y} \in R^m  \\ 
 q = {\bf X} \cdot {\bf Y} = \left\| {\bf X} \right\|\,\left\| {\bf Y} \right\|\;\cos \alpha
 \quad \left| {\;q \in R} \right. \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
which is actually the product of three random variables, among which $\cos \alpha$.
In this case the covariance is defined as a matrix of expected values, which is not what you are considering.

If instead $\bf X , \bf Y$ are two vectors corresponding to the joint sampling (of size $m$) of two **random variables**
$X,Y$ and we are to estimate the correlation between them (which seems what you mean to do) then

- considering the variables to have zero mean, or the sampling mean having been subtracted from the sampling,
- considering the samples to have equal probability to be drawn,
- then the sampling covariance would in fact be
  $$
  {\mathop{\rm cov}} (X,Y) = E\left[ {XY} \right] = \frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {X_k Y_k }
    = \frac{1}{m}{\bf X} \cdot {\bf Y} = \frac{1}{m}\left\| {\bf X} \right\|\,\left\| {\bf Y} \right\|\;\cos \alpha 
  $$
  and
  $$
  \rho _{X,Y}  = \frac{{{\mathop{\rm cov}} (X,Y)}}{{\sqrt {{\mathop{\rm cov}} (XX){\mathop{\rm cov}} (YY)} }}
   = \cos \alpha 
  $$

Comment: If you mean that $X\cdot Y$ denotes pointwise multiplication, then this is only true for zero-mean random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: yes, you are right: that's for zero mean. However, I wanted to underline the difference between r.v. and expected value.

Comment: Then $X\cdot Y$ must be the dot product of sampled data from the distribution $X,Y$. So this concludes that $\rho$ and $\cos(\theta)$ are not equality but approximation?

Comment: @12775: I added some clarifications